# protobuf-net AddField ignores IgnoreListHandling

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have this data structure declaration:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class NotACollectionHolder
{
    public NotACollection some_objects;
}

[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true, ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class NotACollection : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public int some_data;

    // something looks like a collection API
    public void Add(int a) { }
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

I am manually registering field to `MetaType` by the following code:

```
MetaType meta = RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(NotACollectionHolder), false);
ValueMember member = meta.AddField(1, "some_objects", itemType: null, defaultType: null);
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<NotACollectionHolder>();
```

I mark `NotACollection` with `IgnoreListHandling`. I try to force `AddField` to ignore the fact that `NotACollection` looks like collection by providing `itemType: null, defaultType: null`.

Nevertheless, I have `member.ItemType` is not null, and `member.DefaultType` is not null either. And `some_objects` became a `repeated` field in generated `proto`:

```
message NotACollectionHolder {
    repeated int32 some_objects = 1;
}
```

I expect `proto` to look like this:

```
message NotACollection {
   optional int32 some_data = 1 [default = 0];
}
message NotACollectionHolder {
   optional NotACollection some_objects = 1;
}
```

How can I achieve that? What am I doing wrong? How can I force protobuf-net to treat this field like a non collection field?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is indeed a bug in protobuf-net. First way to fix it is to make changes to the source code of protobuf-net: in file MetaType.cs in function

```
private ValueMember AddField(int fieldNumber, string memberName, Type itemType, Type defaultType, object defaultValue)
```

replace line

```
ResolveListTypes(model, miType, ref itemType, ref defaultType);
```

with

```
if (model.FindWithoutAdd(miType)?.IgnoreListHandling == true)
{
    itemType = null;
    defaultType = null;
}
else
    ResolveListTypes(model, miType, ref itemType, ref defaultType);
```

Another way is to use reflection to set private fields `itemType` and `defaultType` of the object `ValueMember` to `null` after adding field:

```
ValueMember m = meta.AddField(++last_field_number, f.Name, f.ItemType, f.DefaultType);
m.GetType().GetField("itemType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(m, null);
m.GetType().GetField("defaultType", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(m, null);
```

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug or limitation with the [`RuntimeTypeModel`](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual#without) API.

The method that determines whether a [`ValueMember`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/ValueMember.cs) is a collection is [`RuntimeTypeModel.ResolveListTypes()`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/RuntimeTypeModel.cs#L1851).  It tries to infer the collection item type when the incoming `itemType` is null.  When building a contract for `NotACollectionHolder` using only static attributes, for instance by doing:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
var schema = model.GetSchema(typeof(NotACollectionHolder));
```

Then [`ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour(bool isEnum, ProtoMemberAttribute normalizedAttribute)`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1097) is called to create an initialize the `ValueMember`.  It has the following logic:

```
        // check for list types
        ResolveListTypes(model, effectiveType, ref itemType, ref defaultType);
        // but take it back if it is explicitly excluded
        if(itemType != null)
        { // looks like a list, but double check for IgnoreListHandling
            int idx = model.FindOrAddAuto(effectiveType, false, true, false);
            if(idx >= 0 && model[effectiveType].IgnoreListHandling)
            {
                itemType = null;
                defaultType = null;
            }
        }
```

Notice the explicit check for `IgnoreListHandling`?  This correctly prevents `some_objects` from being serialized as a collection.

Conversely, if adds the `ValueMember` programmatically as follows:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
var meta = model.Add(typeof(NotACollectionHolder), false);
var member = meta.AddField(1, "some_objects", null, null);
var schema = model.GetSchema(typeof(NotACollectionHolder));
```

Then [`MetaType.AddField(int fieldNumber, string memberName, Type itemType, Type defaultType, object defaultValue)`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1395) is called, which simply does:

```
        ResolveListTypes(model, miType, ref itemType, ref defaultType);
```

Notice there is no check for `IgnoreListHandling`?  This is the cause of your problem.

Unfortunately, [`ValueType.itemType`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/ValueMember.cs#L36) is read-only and [`MetaType[int fieldNumber]`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/MetaType.cs#L1546) is get-only so there doesn't seem to be a simple API to call to fix this.  You might consider [reporting an issue](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/issues).

The only workaround I could find is to introduce a surrogate for the `NotACollectionHolder` type like so:

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class NotACollectionHolderSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    internal NotACollectionSurrogate some_objects;

    public static implicit operator NotACollectionHolder(NotACollectionHolderSurrogate input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;
        return new NotACollectionHolder { some_objects = input.some_objects };
    }

    public static implicit operator NotACollectionHolderSurrogate(NotACollectionHolder input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;
        return new NotACollectionHolderSurrogate { some_objects = input.some_objects };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
internal class NotACollectionSurrogate
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int some_data;

    public static implicit operator NotACollection(NotACollectionSurrogate input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;
        return new NotACollection { some_data = input.some_data };
    }

    public static implicit operator NotACollectionSurrogate(NotACollection input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return null;
        return new NotACollectionSurrogate { some_data = input.some_data };
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
var model = TypeModel.Create();
model.Add(typeof(NotACollectionHolder), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(NotACollectionHolderSurrogate));

var schema = model.GetSchema(typeof(NotACollectionHolder));
```

The contract generated is as required:

```
message NotACollectionHolderSurrogate {
   optional NotACollectionSurrogate some_objects = 1;
}
message NotACollectionSurrogate {
   optional int32 some_data = 1 [default = 0];
}
```