# Serializing an IEnumerable in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net, protobuf-net.grpc

I have a library of fairly heavy-weight DTOs that is currently being used by some WCF services. We are attempting to bring it into protobuf-net world, with as little modification as possible. One particular set of items is giving me trouble in serialization. I'm going to simply them here because it gets a little complicated, but the gist of the problem is:

```cs
public class Key
{
   public string Id {get; set;}
}

public class KeyCollection : IEnumerable<Key>
{
   private readonly List<Key> list;

#region IEnumerable
   // etc...
#endregion
}

public class Item
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ContainerBase
{ }

public abstract class ContainerBase<T> : ContainerBase
   where T : Item
{ }

public abstract class ContainerType1Base : ContainerBase<Item>
{
   public KeyCollection Keys { get; set; }
}

public class ContainerType1 : ContainerType1Base
{ }
```

I've left out the decorators because I don't they're the problem, mostly because if I add `void Add(Key item) {  }` to `KeyCollection` the whole thing seems to work. Otherwise, I run into problems attempting to serialize an instance of `ContainerType1`.

Actually, changing the signature of `KeyCollection` is kind of prohibitive, so I'm attempting to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42600663/protobuf-net-addfield-ignores-ignorelisthandling) to try to do it programatically. Specifically, setting `itemType` and `defaultType` to null on the "Keys" `ValueMember` of `ContainerType1`, `ContainerType1Base` and `ContainerBase<Item>`. I also set `IgnoreListHandling` to `true` on `KeyCollection`... which totally doesn't work. I get a generic "failed to deserialize" exception on the client, which I can post here if it would help. On the server side, I serialize it out using `Serializer.Serialize()`, and I spit out `Serializer.GetProto<>()` as well as JSON of the object, and they all seem to be work okay.

How can I turn off the list handling? Related to that, is there a way to turn on extra debugging while serializing to try to get some more information of the problem?

Comment: IgnoreListHandling should absolutely work. Do you perhaps have a *runnable* minimal repro where I can see the same thing you're seeing? Details probably matter. Also, what library version are you using? Thanks.

Comment: I can try making a small repo that I can share which exhibits this behavior. I'm using protobuf-net.Grpc.Native, v1.0.123.

Comment: I forgot to mention (or rather it didn't seem important, but it actually might be) that this is done in the context of a Grpc call. So the whole `ContainerType1` is being returned by some method reply.

Comment: well, I wrote both of those libraries, so... I *should* be able to help :) a repro would really help (btw; if you comment back with an update - try to @ me, i.e. @foof - that makes it more reliable that I'll get notified)

Comment: @MarcGravell you're right, I tried reproducing my problem with a small subset of the DTO library and I was able to 1, reproduce it and 2, `IgnoreListHandling` my way out of it. The original DTO library is still throwing on deserialization.. is there a way to turn on more debugging info? All I'm getting is "failed to deserialize".

Comment: is that "... request message" or "... response message"? so I know where to look

Comment: I'm *guessing* this is "response message", meaning: client receiving server response; unfortunately the Google code (not protobuf-net.Grpc) [loses the original exception](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/a1ad4800da2bb02c843bdaea8fb06518916b6fba/src/csharp/Grpc.Core/Internal/AsyncCallBase.cs#L349-L355); I'm going to log an issue with the Google folks, and see if they'd take a patch that exposed it in the `.DebugException`. FYI, I can also think of ways of investigating this using a "custom marshaller", but can I play a hunch? are you on .NET Framework? Possibly a missing binding redirect?

Comment: Issue logged: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24784

Comment: another way of debugging this: on the server, generate the data you want to simulate, and do: `var ms = new MemoryStream(); Serializer.Serialize(ms, yourDataHere); var payload = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());` and get hold of `payload` (it is just a `string` now); now go to the client and reverse this: `var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(thatValue)); Serialize.Deserialize<YourTypeHere>(ms);` and see what it says

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes! That did it, thank you! I had a class somewhere in there that had a non-parameterless constructor. If you copy/paste that comment as an answer, I can just accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the code shown looks fine. Unfortunately, there's currently a ["feature" in gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24784) that means that it discards the original exception when a marshaller (serializer) fails for some reason, so gRPC does not currently expose the actual problem. I have submitted a fix for this - it may or may not be accepted.

In the interim, I suggest that you simply remove gRPC from the equation, and simulate just the marshaller workload; to do this, on the server: generate the data you are trying to send, and do:

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(ms, yourDataHere);
var payload = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
```

and obtain the value of `payload` (which is just a `string`). Now at the client, reverse this:

```cs
var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(thatStringValue));
Serialize.Deserialize<YourTypeHere>(ms);
```

My expectation here is that this should throw an exception that will tell you what the actual problem is.

---

If the gRPC change gets merged, then the fault *should* be available via:

```cs
catch (RpcException fault)
{
    var originalFault = fault.Status.DebugException;
    // ^^^
}
```